# Pyplot.imshow() and pyplot.show() displaying intermittently

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been working with pyplot.imshow() all week.

Everytime I debug and I hit pyplot.imshow(), an image displays.  Now, all of a sudden, no image displays until I hit pyplot.show().

What is going on here? What has changed?

Here is my setup:

I was using Pycharm.

I loaded matplotlib, sklearn, numpy, pandas.

I created a couple of classes in a separate file, and was running the classes to produce images in the file in question.

During the production of the images, I had to look up "imshow" (my experience level with python is only a few months).  After implementing "imshow", the images appeared when I passed the "imshow" line in a debugging session. That is just the way it behaved.

---

I used this repeatedly for days.  Then, *all of a sudden* (and I may have closed and reopened Pycharm, I can't remember), the "imshow()" function started **intermittently** displaying an image (sometimes it did, sometimes it didn't).

So I started adding "show()" beneath the "imshow()" calls...and that worked (sort of).  Very soon, however *that* started working only intermittently.  I would pass "show()" during debugging sessions and *nothing* would show up.

---

This mysterious behavior just began.  I changed zero settings.  No one with computer knowledge had any access to the PC (just my parents during the superbowl...).

Whether "imshow()" is supposed to display something or not, "show()" should always work, right?  How is it that both of these functions just stopped working as expected, with only a possible IDE restart that I'm reasonably sure didn't happen...(no computer restart)...and no python package installs.

(the only thing I installed was notepadqq...but the functions stopped working properly several hours after that)

Comment: What is happening now is the [desired behavior](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#use-show). Maybe you had interactave mode on, before. That's hard to tell without more information. Btw, the title does not match the question (`plot()` vs `show()`).

Comment: @Kazemakase All I did was load matplotlib.pyplot as plt.  Then I used IMshow.  It was showing up all the time...then, all of a sudden, it started showing up about half the time...the other half of the time, I needed to add plt.show()...and even then, it didn't show sometimes.

Comment: @mel I executed in pycharm.  The behavior started changing in the middle of the session.  I did *nothing* to the settings of anything.

Comment: @Kazemakase thanks for the typo pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have changed the way you run your script (e.g. from `ipython` with the `--pylab` or `--matplotlib` switches to the standard `python` interpreter) or have changed version or default mode of `ipython`.
In any case, if you use `pyplot.ion()` before calling `pyplot.imshow(...)`, the image should display automatically.